# How do I reference android WearApp model classes from inside mobile app?

Tags: android, gradle

I can't figure out how to keep things DRY with my models between my Android mobile+wear app.

settings.gradle

```
include ':mobile', ':wear'
```

mobile/build.gradle:

```
wearApp project(':wear')
```

mobile/MobileActivity.java

```
import models.Model;
```

wear/models/Model.java

```
class Model {
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Model'
```

Is there no way to reference the classes created in the wear app?  Do I have to create a separate module that is common to both mobile+wear modules?